# Is there a way in Python to get a sub matrix as in Matlab?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

For example, let's say that I have the following matrices in Matlab:

```
A = zeros(10)
B = ones(2,2)
```

I want to add the matrix A with B in specific positions of A that are stored like this:

```
locations = [1, 3]
```

I can do this:

```
A(locations, locations) = A(locations, locations) + B
```

So the job is done. In python, I would like to the same using NumPy arrays, like:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.zeros([10,10])
B = np.ones([2,2])
locations = np.array([0, 2]) #Because NumPy arrays are zero indexed
A[locations, locations] = A[locations, locations] + B
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (2,2) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (2,)
```

Does anyone know how can I do this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by (1,3) or (0,2) matlab/ python wise, you mean you want to change 4 things or just 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [126]: A = np.zeros((5,5),int)
In [127]: B = np.arange(1,5).reshape(2,2)
In [128]: idx = np.array([0,2])
```

In `numpy` indexing with 2 1d arrays produces a 'diagonal', the points (0,0) and (2,2).  In MATLAB you have to use some sort of sub2ind to convert the 2d indexing to 1d.

```
In [129]: A[idx,idx]
Out[129]: array([0, 0])
```

To get a block (as MATLAB) does we have to take advantage of broadcasting:

```
In [130]: A[idx[:,None],idx]
Out[130]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 0]])
In [131]: A[idx[:,None],idx]=B
In [132]: A
Out[132]: 
array([[1, 0, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 0, 4, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

This, and other indexing details, is covered in

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I needed :D

Answer (score 0):

```
A = np.zeros([10,10])
B = np.ones([2,2])
print(B)
A[:2,:2]=B
print(A)

#output B

[[1. 1.]
 [1. 1.]]

#output A

[[1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Comment: is that what you want so I can elaborate more?